# ros2 humble rqt drop-down menu

Tags: parameters, ros2, rqt

I am trying to use parameter in ROS2.

In ROS1, we can use parameter generator to edit cfg file and generate drop-down menu in rqt.

[drop-down menu in qrt at ros1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY045.png)
drop-down menu in rqt

But I don't know how to generate in ROS2.

I have tried parameter descriptor and yaml file but still can not make it.

Please help. Thanks.

I have tried to use parameter descriptor.

It can generate a drag bar but no drop-down menu.

I also tried to use yaml file to make parameter multiple value (in a array).

But it did not show a drop - down menu but disappear in rqt.

Comment: As suggested by the ros2 tag, please ask ROS 2 related questions on https://robotics.stackexchange.com from now on.

Comment: OK, got it. I post at here: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24906/ros2-humble-rqt-drop-down-menu